# A string in multiple classes iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, string, sdk

so I'm making an app and one page the user is going to type in a username and password.  It will be stored in a string.  Say this string was stored in the setting.m/.h files.  How do I access them from other classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always use Keychain to store usernames and passwords, and since it's stored securely and only accessible to your app. See Apple's [GenericKeychain sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GenericKeychain/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007797):

> This sample shows how to add, query for, remove, and update a keychain
>   item of generic class type. Also demonstrates the use of shared
>   keychain items. All classes exhibit very similar behavior so the
>   included examples will scale to the other classes of Keychain Item:
>   Internet Password, Certificate, Key, and Identity.

If you want to store other strings, ints, floats, or arrays that aren't sensitive, then you should look into using [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: thanks to your fast response, I'm 14 and learning so thanks for your help

Comment: @user974052 You're welcome. And welcome to SO. Be sure to search around for answers on this site before posting questions (we don't like duplicate questions). Good luck with your apps!